# Three.js - How to smooth data like in d3.js

Tags: d3.js, three.js, smoothing, interpolation

I need to know if in **Three.js** there is something who look like [.interpolate("basis")  **(d3.js)**](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1016220)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer.
With **tween.js**, i can do something very close to **interpolate("basis") -> D3.js**

CatmullRom is the answer and the link is [here -> array interpolation](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/blob/master/examples/06_array_interpolation.html).

More information about [CatmullRom here](http://books.google.fr/books?id=UvrYAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=CatmullRom+threejs&source=bl&ots=21iBkoPt3Q&sig=PciDdJXyvbtmvok57iw044Y33d8&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=HriAVMrXGJfwaN6egeAM&ved=0CGgQ6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=CatmullRom%20threejs&f=false)